# Apache2 Forward and Reverse Proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2, proxypass

I have a web server and some load balancers, to avoid exposing the external IP's of the LB's I wanted to install a Ubuntu Apache2 (doesn't have to be) based Proxy. I want it to:
Client ---> Domain ---> Proxy ---> Web Server
and reply:
Web Server ---> Proxy ---> Domain ---> Client

I have googled and googled and get similar answers but none seem to work, each time I get this:
Client ---> Domain ---> Proxy ---> Web Server
and reply:
Web Server ---> Client

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid! Please be gentle
My apache2 site conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / https://12.33.44.55/
ProxyPassReverse / https://12.33.44.55/
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean that you don't want to expose the IPs of the load balancers? Why do you even have them, then?

Comment: I don't want to expose the IP of anything ideally, I want them to do their jobs but pass the data back through the same Proxy

Comment: You're exposing the IP of this redundant proxy, too. At some point someone has to be able to know how to reach your web site! It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Im fine with exposing the Proxys IP, and I understand this seems silly to load balance then force back through a single point of failure but its sadly my task at hand. Thanks